# performance of click event on body vs. rebinding for fruture

Tags: jquery, performance

I have two options:

```
$("button").on('click',function(){
   $("#myDiv").prepend('<p>new paragraph</p>');
});
$('body').on('click','p',function(){
   console.log('clicked paragraph');
});
```

OR

```
$("button").on('click',function(){
   $("#myDiv").prepend('<p>new paragraph</p>');
   $("p").on('click',function(){
      console.log('clicked paragraph');
   });
});
```

---

Which will be faster? Does either method haev any known problems with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to worry about speed with delegated event handlers. The difference in speed is however long it takes the browser to propagate the event up to the ancestor (trivial) and then the time it takes jQuery to check the selectors for registered delegated handlers on that ancestory (`body` in your case) against the actual path the event took (also trivial).

But note that handlers on the actual element are triggered first, and so they have the opportunity to stop the event before it ever gets to the `body`. That's usually the biggest hassle with delegated handlers.

---

Note that your second code snippet has an issue, though: Every time you add a paragraph, you're setting a `click` handler on existing paragraphs — including the ones you've *already* put a click handler on! You probably want to avoid that. :-)

If you want to use the second example but avoid that problem, you could do this:

```
$("button").on('click',function(){
   $('<p>new paragraph</p>').prependTo("#myDiv").on('click',function(){
      console.log('clicked paragraph');
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll stick with the first one here.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the difference would not be noticeable unless you were doing it many, many, many times.  I'd say that the 2nd solution is cleaner, but I'd modify it so that it doesn't preclude you from using p tags for non-clickable purposes:

```
$("#myDiv").find('p').on('click',function(){
    console.log('clicked paragraph');
 });
```